# VIm : How to use only the "mouse scrolling" without the other feature of :set mouse=a

Tags: vim, scroll, text-cursor

I just discovered `:set mouse=a`. Amazing thing, it allows my coworkers to scroll over my openend files.

But here is the thing : I really don't want the cursor to move when I left-click somewhere. I don't want either the standard cursor which `:set mouse=a` brings (I want to keep the default text cursor).

In others words : is there a way to **enable mouse scrolling** in VIm *without* enable other support mouse stuff ?

Thanks.

EDIT - **other idea** : can I bind the `wheel mouse UP` to do the same thing that `Page Up` key ? It would be awesome !

Comment: Why can't your coworkers simply use `<C-f>`, `<C-b>` and friends? What's the point of using a mouse if you can't use it to point at something on the screen?

Comment: Using the mouse only for scrolling is a must-have for my coworkers who read my code on my screen (and they hate VIm) :p

Comment: I just found `<MiddleRelease>`, but it is not the click I want to bind, but the scrolling up and the scrolling down ... Any idea ?

Comment: I think that looking for a Vim-only solution is the wrong thing to do. You should investigate OS-wide re-binding or see what you can do with your terminal emulator.

Comment: Why it is the wrong thing to do ? I work on Windows, via Putty, and binding scroll UP and Down not appear to me as a bad idea ..

Comment: not bad idea per se but Vim is not very mouse-friendly. You'll have more luck outside of vim than in vim.

Comment: Do you know how to bind the wheel UP to something (in my case, `<C-f>`) ? I want to do some trials.

Comment: No, I don't use windows. Google is your friend, there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20943/discussion-between-ash-and-romainl)

Answer (score 2):

Try this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <LeftMouse> <nop>
```

Comment: Well, it disabled LeftClic, yes, but that's not what I want to do. I just updated my question.